# Radius of sphere formed by equipotential surface of point dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

One of the Equipotential surface formed by point electric dipole placed in parallel electric field forms a sphere enclosing the dipole.how to find the radius of the sphere?

Comment: Shouldn't it be infinte?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework problem, so I'll just give some ideas on how to start this problem.

The electric potential of a point dipole $\vec{p} = p \hat{z}$ can be written as
$$
V_\text{dip} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\vec{p} \cdot \hat{r}}{r^2} = \frac{p}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\hat{z} \cdot \vec{r}}{r^3}.
$$
The electric potential of a pair of parallel plates that are creating an electric field $\vec{E} = E \hat{z}$ is
$$
V_\text{plates} = - \vec{E} \cdot \vec{r} = - E \hat{z} \cdot \vec{r}.
$$
(We have implicitly assumed that $V_\text{plates} = 0$ at the location of the dipole.)  Add these two quantities together, and remember that the quantity $\hat{z} \cdot \vec{r}$ is never constant over the surface of a sphere;  this will allow you to solve for $r$ in terms of $p$ and $E$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT- Split the dipole into into components, such that one of the components of the field at the equipotential surface is axial and one is equatorial. Draw these along with the applied field at that point. Since the surface is equipotential, the net tangential field must be zero. So, write $\vec E_{tangential}$=0. You should get something like $(\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}E_{app}})^{1/3}$. You may have to use the equation for field due to a dipole at any arbitrary external point, though it can be bypassed by splitting into components like I mentioned.